# DC resistance seen by a terminal?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: samples]

I can't understand, how,

- The DC resistance seen by the inverting terminal of the 1st op amp is R1 || R2.
- The DC resistance seen by the inverting terminal of the 2nd op amp (which in fact turns into the 3rd op amp at low frequency and dc) is R2.

What does it mean by resistance seen by a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is incomplete, in the sense that the left end of R1 is presumed to be connected to a voltage source.

Also, the output of the opamp is considered a voltage source, and the input of the opamp is considered to be a current source — a tiny one that represents the input bias current of the opamp.

When analyzing a network that contains multiple sources, you use the principle of superposition: Consider each source one at a time, replacing the other sources with short circuits (voltage sources) or open circuits (current sources).

Therefore, when analyzing the current source that represents the input bias current, you short the left end of R1 to ground, and also short the right end of R2 to ground. Now you have a current source connected to two parallel resistors.

In the second diagram, the capacitor blocks the DC current, so even though the left side of the capacitor is connected to ground, no current flows through R1 and you're just left with R2 connected to ground as the "load" on the current source.

Comment: makes sense, but why should i consider the output as a voltage source?

Comment: Because that's the definition of an "ideal" opamp. But even with a non-ideal opamp, in most cases the effective output resistance will be several orders of magnitude lower than the value of the feedback resistor, so it can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I think this theme is common when doing small signal analysis (usually done when analyzing transistors and their circuits when an small-signal AC voltage is superimposed on a DC voltage). In small signal analysis, you view all power and ground rails as a common ground. It looks like in your analysis, any open circle represents a "ground". The reason more things may look like a ground in this kind analysis is because they can source or sink infinite current. A standard ground is just thought of as a place that sinks all current. A power rail sources as much current as the circuit can take because it just gives a voltage. The output of the op-amp seen in your schematics also has the ability to source or sink infinite current (in the ideal case). That's one of the properties of the output side of an ideal op-amp. The input terminal is probably seen as another "ground" terminal because what's driving it would likely be another op-amp. Once you understand that, you can take all "grounds" in a circuit and connect them. Then when you're given a point in your circuit to analyze, you just determine how much total resistance to any of the grounds there is.